# Safari does not stop downloading media after removing src and calling load()

Tags: javascript, safari, html5-audio

After an HTML media element is paused, the browser keeps downloading the media.

MDN describes how the download can be stopped by removing the media element's `src` attribute and calling `HTMLMediaElement.load()`: [MDN - Stopping the download of media](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Audio_and_video_delivery#Stopping_the_download_of_media).

In Safari, this is not sufficient to stop the media continuing to download. In the Web Inspector Network tab, the transfer can be seen to continue. This is despite the `load()` method being supported and the appropriate events being sent when it is called. (See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/load#Usage_notes).)

Using the following example and monitoring the network, you should be able to see the behaviour in Safari differ compared to Chrome, for example.

```
<audio
   controls preload="none" type="audio/mpeg"
   src="http://bbcmedia.ic.llnwd.net/stream/bbcmedia_radio1_mf_p"
/>

<script>
    const mediaEl = document.querySelector('audio');

    mediaEl.addEventListener('abort', (e) => {
        console.log('abort', e.target);
    });
    mediaEl.addEventListener('emptied', (e) => {
        console.log('emptied', e.target);
    });
    mediaEl.addEventListener('pause', (e) => {
        e.target.removeAttribute('src');
        e.target.load();
    });
</script>
```

Removing the media element from the DOM is not sufficient to stop the download either.

```
mediaEl.addEventListener('pause', (e) => {
    e.target.parentNode.removeChild(e.target);
});
```

Is there a way to work around this issue in Safari and stop the download initiated by the media element?

My use case involves an audio stream. I do not want the browser to continue buffering after the user has stopped playback.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
The only good workaround I've found is putting the audio tag in separate html and loading that into an iframe - then adding an event listener that reloads the audio tag's page when the stream is paused.

Comment: Thx!  I should have worded it differently.  I shared my workaround, but also wanted to know what resolution (if any) the OP had come up with.

Comment: Whoops; I missed that you had a workaround in there. I reworded your answer to remove that bit because it might get your answer flagged by others as well. If the OP had a resolution, we hope they would've shared it here but an answer is the wrong place to request that. Once you got 50 reputation however, you can post a comment :) Sorry for the rough start and welcome to StackOverflow \o/